# How do I use custom image as a button background in Wix toolset bootstrapper custom theme?

Tags: wix

I am quite confused with how to set an image as a button background. Documentation tells it may be possible in some way using the ButtonImage, ButtonHoverImage, ButtonSelectedImage elements but I've got noting really working.

I am using Wix v4 and didn't find a clear example to get it done.

This try is compiled by Wix but installer don't run when launched

```html
<Button Name="InstallButtonBlob" X="-251" Y="-11" Width="138" Height="42" TabStop="yes" >
    <Text>Blob</Text>
    <ButtonImage  ImageFile="installer_button_bg.png"/>
    <ButtonHoverImage  ImageFile="installer_button_bg.png"/>
    <ButtonSelectedImage  ImageFile="installer_button_bg.png"/>
</Button>
```

installer_button_bg.png is a picture that is 138 x 42 in size.